# Return part of a string with variable length

Tags: postgresql, regular-expression, substring

I have data in a table column like below:

```
host=0.0.0.0 port=5432 dbname=database_name user=pglogicaluser
host=0.0.0.0 port=5432 dbname=database_name2 user=pglogicaluser
```

I want to write a query to get the database names only like below:

```
database_name
database_name2
```

I could come up with something like:

```
select substring(column_name, '.+dbname=(.*)$') from table_name;
```

However, I couldn't figure how to stop the extraction before the `user` keyword starts.

Comment: Yes all the data is from one column.

Comment: Is the database name `UNIQUE`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to include a space after the regex group that acts as a delimiter to separate the user keyword from the text you want to match. To make the regex match in that case, an additional "any other character" is needed.

```
substring(column_name, '.+dbname=(.*) .*$')
```

Comment: Thank you that worked. I run the below regex and it worked too.

`SUBSTRING (column_name ,  '(?:dbname=)(.*?)(?:user)' )`

Comment: @SayadXiarkakh - performance will be terrible!

Answer (score 0):

If this string always has the form

`host=x port=y dbname=name user=z`

then there's a **far** better (i.e. faster) way of doing what you want. I did the following (all of the code below is available here):

```
CREATE TABLE str
(
  pg_str TEXT
);
```

Populate it:

```
INSERT INTO str VALUES
('host=0.0.0.0 port=5432 dbname=database_name user=pglogicaluser'),
('host=0.0.0.0 port=5432 dbname=database_name2 user=pglogicaluser');
```

First we use the [SPLIT_PART()](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-string-functions/postgresql-split_part/) function. Its signature is SPLIT_PART(string, delimiter, position) ([manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/functions-string.html))

So, we run:

```
SELECT
  SPLIT_PART(pg_str, ' ', 3)
FROM str;
```

Result:

```
split_part
dbname=database_name
dbname=database_name2
```

Next, we apply the [REPLACE()](https://www.commandprompt.com/education/how-to-replace-a-string-using-replace-function-in-postgresql/) (same manual page) function to remove the `dbname=` part above:

```
SELECT
  REPLACE(SPLIT_PART(pg_str, ' ', 3), 'dbname=', '') AS dbname
FROM str;
```

Result:

```
dbname
database_name
database_name2
```

Now, what you could do is something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE str ADD COLUMN db TEXT GENERATED ALWAYS AS 
(REPLACE(SPLIT_PART(pg_str, ' ', 3), 'dbname=', '')) STORED;
```

so, now you don't have to perform complex queries on the fly - every time you `INSERT` or `UPDATE` your `pg_connection_str`, the `db` field will be modified accordingly. There is a space penalty to be paid, but it's relatively small.

As a general rule of thumb, if it can be done without regexes, then do it without regexes!